# How to get the selected item of a combo box to a string variable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

Can anyone tell me how to get the selected item of a `ComboBox` to a `string` variable?

```
string selected = cmbbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(selected);
```

This gives me `System.Data.DataRowView` in my `MessageBox`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Try this:

```
string selected = this.ComboBox.GetItemText(this.ComboBox.SelectedItem);
MessageBox.Show(selected);
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this over `this.ComboBox.Text`?

Comment: @Mike E: Yes, there is a reason. ComboBox.Text gets or sets the text associated with this control (has nothing in common with selected item): http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @LeoChapiro Regarding the `ComboBox.Text` property, according to Microsoft documentation it says: "The string of the currently selected item."

Comment: @Simple Microsoft documentation is unfortunately Microsoft documentation, i.e. frequently wrong and misleading.
You put this in a SelectionChanged callback and SelectedIndex and SelectedItem will reflect the change. Text will not.

Answer (score 18):

### 2023 Update...

You can use as below:

```
string selected = comboBox.selectedItem.ToString();
```

or

```
string selected = comboBox.SelectedText;
```

Answer (score 10):

Test [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315237/get-the-combobox-text-in-c-sharp)

```
  var selected = this.ComboBox.GetItemText(this.ComboBox.SelectedItem);
  MessageBox.Show(selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var selected = cmbbox.GetItemText(cmbbox.Text);
MessageBox.Show(selected);
```

Comment: Why use the `Text` property instead of `SelectedItem` as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15186131/150605)?

Comment: This did work for me, i guess it would be a preference thing. i Could not get the results as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:
CombBoxItem comboBoxItem = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem
string text = comboBoxItem.content.ToString();

Answer (score -3):

```
SelectedText = this.combobox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
```