# How to get value of the selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the value of the selected item of the combobox. I'm using wpf and c#.

I make something like that:

```
 String c = Combobox.SelectedItem.Tag
```

No, all the answers are wrong here, but perhaps it is also a bit 'my fault because I could not express myself well.
However, for each item in the ComboBox associate a value, for example:

```
Item1 (Value) => Home (Tag)<br>
Item2 (Value) => Away (Tag)<br>
Item3 (Value) => Half (Tag)<br>
```

and this is September Tag like:

Now I want get this tag When the related item is selected, for example:
user select Item1 and in the variable is valorize Home with tags ...
But isn't working. So what is the way to get it?

Comment: `Combobox.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the selected item of a combo box to a string variable in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186093/how-to-get-the-selected-item-of-a-combo-box-to-a-string-variable-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `combobox.SelectedItem` is the object the the combobox is bound to. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4902454/880990

Comment: I've updated the question, because I think I misspoke

Comment: Do you mean something like using a `Dictionary`? That would have a key and value, so you would have a tag as your key and a value as your visible piece.

Comment: I already use this solution for storage the value. I want to know if there is another smart way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String c=combobox.SelectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
string c = comboBox1.SelectedValue != null ? comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: No need for a ternary, it should exist already. All you need is `string c = comboBox1.SelectedValue;`

Comment: SelectedValue returns an object, you cannot cast to string directly.