# SelectedItem of ComboBox does not update in c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a WinForms project in which I **dynamically** add a ComboBox (meaning I cannot access it in the designer for instance) in an initialize method in a User Control. That initialize method is executed each time I activate the form on which the User Control is located by responding to the activate event from the form. I store the ComboBox in a List on my User Control so that I can reference it later. When I press the Update button on my form, I execute a method on my User Control where I read the SelectedItem from my ComboBox that is in the List I saved during the Initialize method.

However, this only works correctly the first time I press the Update button. When I select a different value in the ComboBox and push the button again, I can see in the debugger that the SelectedItem property has not updated and is still on the previous value.

What am I missing?

**How I add my ComboBox during runtime** (in the Initialize method in my User Control, executed each time the form is activated)

```
ComboBox c_options = new ComboBox();
c_options.AutoSize = true;
c_options.Location = new Point(c_standard_label.Bounds.Right + spacing, c_standard_label.Bounds.Top);
c_options.Font = new Font("Arial", 10F, FontStyle.Regular);
c_options.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
c_options.Size = new Size(c_options_panel.Width - (c_standard_label.Bounds.Right + spacing), spacing);
var bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
bindingSource1.DataSource = _view.ComplianceOptions[i];
c_options.DataSource = bindingSource1.DataSource;
c_options_panel.Controls.Add(c_options);
// this is the list in which I store the combobox
ComplianceThresholds.Add(c_options);
```

**How I read the SelectedItem** (in the Update method in my User Control, executed when the Update button on the form is pressed)

```
public void UpdateAnalysisParameters(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var temp2 = new List<string>();
    foreach (var i in ComplianceThresholds)
    {
        // here I check the selected item, which is always the same.
        temp2.Add(i.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
    _view.SelectedComplianceThresholds = temp2;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the selected item of a combo box to a string variable in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186093/how-to-get-the-selected-item-of-a-combo-box-to-a-string-variable-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I can apply your sample code successfully and there is no problem. Maybe wrong thing is about your `BindingSource`. What is `ComplianceOptions` instance, array or something else? If you change your `c_options.DataSource = bindingSource1.DataSource` code with simple string array object you can see everything ok. I mean that delete (or comment) this line and add `c_options.Items.Add("one"); c_options.Items.Add("two"); c_options.Items.Add("three");` and try.

Comment: @iBener I have tried it with commenting the line and adding your lines. The result is the same. But I have found out something. Please see my second edit.

Comment: Ok, so, question is simple, when you want to add combobox in your form? On a button click or when some event raised?

Comment: @iBener The combobox is added in the activate event of the form.

Comment: Sorry I'm so confused. I don't understand your question. Please ask your question more clearly.

Comment: @iBener I have tried to rephrase the question.

Comment: @NikS. Could you remove the duplicate thing since this is a different question?